# How to create XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create an XML and return it as a string.  Can anyone tell me how to create the following XML using `XmlDocument`?

```
<outputs>
  <output name="" value="" type=""></output>
  <output name="" value="" type=""></output>
  <output name="" value="" type=""></output>
</outputs>
```

**UPDATE**

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            var xmlNode=xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration,"outputs","namespace");
            xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlNode);

            var xmlElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement("", "output", "");
            xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlElement);
```

Comment: What have you tried, and why do you need to use `XmlDocument`? (I vastly prefer `XDocument`.)

Comment: ok then please show me an example of XDocument...for the above XML.

Comment: see this for example: [XDocument](http://csharp-guide.blogspot.com/2012/06/xdocument-examples.html)

Comment: Again, what have you tried? It's important to show that you've put in some effort before asking the question. There are dozens - probably hundreds - of XML tutorials for C#.

Comment: I have put my partial code of effort in UPDATE Section..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Create XmlDocument
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

//Create the root element
XmlNode outputsElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("outputs");

//Create the child element
XmlElement Element = xmlDoc.CreateElement("output");

//Create "name" Attribute
XmlAttribute nameAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
Element.Attributes.Append(nameAtt);

//Create "value" Attribute
XmlAttribute valueAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
Element.Attributes.Append(valueAtt);

//Create "type" Attribute
XmlAttribute typeAtt = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("type");
Element.Attributes.Append(typeAtt);

//Append child element into root element
outputsElement.AppendChild(Element);
```

and to return it as string:
xmlDoc.OuterXml;

Answer (score 12):

I think you should consider using `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("outputs",
                            new XElement("output",
                                new XAttribute("name", ""),
                                new XAttribute("value", ""),
                                new XAttribute("type", "")),
                            new XElement("output",
                                new XAttribute("name", ""),
                                new XAttribute("value", ""),
                                new XAttribute("type", "")),         
                            new XElement("output",
                                new XAttribute("name", ""),
                                new XAttribute("value", ""),
                                new XAttribute("type", ""))));
```

You can than easily write the xml into a string:

```
var myXmlString = doc.ToString();
```

You can also achieve the same goal with `XDocument.Parse()` static method:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<outputs><output></output> (...) </outputs>");
```

You can add content using loop as well:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("outputs"));
var root = doc.Root;
foreach(var o in outputs)
{
    root.Add(new XElement("output",
                 new XAttribute("name", o.Name),
                 new XAttribute("value", o.Value),
                 new XAttribute("type", o.Type)));
}
```

Comment: how to apply foreach loop in above since the number of occurence of <output name="" value="" type=""></output> is not known...

Answer (score 1):

```
        string str = "<outputs><output name=\"\" value=\"\" type=\"\"></output><output name=\"\" value=\"\" type=\"\"></output><output name=\"\" value=\"\" type=\"\"></output></outputs>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(str);
```

And for creating a string again.

```
        string toString = string.Empty;
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

            doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);

            toString = stringWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you a lot, it is a great example about how to Read and Write to an xml file:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx

Example code about how to Create elements and a whole XML file, using c# code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new file in C:\\ dir
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\myXmFile.xml", null);
        // Opens the document
        textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        // Write comments
        textWriter.WriteComment("First Comment XmlTextWriter Sample Example");
        textWriter.WriteComment("myXmlFile.xml in root dir");
        // Write first element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Student");
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("r", "RECORD", "urn:record");
        // Write next element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Name", "");
        textWriter.WriteString("Student");
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        // Write one more element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", ""); textWriter.WriteString("Colony");
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        // WriteChars
        char[] ch = new char[3];
        ch[0] = 'a';
        ch[1] = 'r';
        ch[2] = 'c';
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Char");
        textWriter.WriteChars(ch, 0, ch.Length);
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        // Ends the document.
        textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        // close writer
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Although perfectly valid, that was how Microsoft expected us to write XML when they first released .NET. Thankfully things have moved on since then, and the Linq-to-XML answer provided by @MarcinJuraszek is far superior.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny So it should be considered as a valid answer. Link is provided, code is provided. There is no reason to downvote here.