# parsing xml and form dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dictionary

I have this xml format.i want to form dictionary using c#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <key value="22.wav">
    <Index>1</Index>
  </key>
  <key value="22.wav">
    <Index>0</Index>
  </key>
  <key value="22.wav">
    <Index>7</Index>
  </key>
  <key value="22.wav">
    <Index>13</Index>
  </key>
</root>
```

How do i form?.Please Help me.Here Key is ex:value=22.wav and value=1 when i try to form dictionary It shows error same key with value already added

Comment: what is the key and value? what have you tried?

Comment: @Ehsan key is value="22.wav" and value is index when i try to form dictionary it shows error same key with value already added

Comment: ur xml is throwing exception

Comment: Eh? Dictionary has unique keys. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @munisamy dictionary can have unique keys only. That is why you are getting error.

Comment: i want same key with different values

Comment: @Ehsan Is It not possible in dictionary?

Comment: @munisamy no. It is if you make a dictionary like this Dictionary<int,List<string>>. Then against one key you can have multiple values in a list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create xml format c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651725/create-xml-format-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dictionary using Linq and XLinq:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <key value='22.wav'>
    <Index>1</Index>
  </key>
  <key value='22.wav'>
    <Index>0</Index>
  </key>
  <key value='22.wav'>
    <Index>7</Index>
  </key>
  <key value='22.wav'>
    <Index>13</Index>
  </key>
</root>";

// Convert the string to XLinq
var xe = XElement.Parse(xml);

// Create a dictionary with Linq extension
// Use int ("Index") as the key
// Use string (key[@value]) as the value
var dict = xe.Descendants("Index")
             .ToDictionary(k => int.Parse(k.Value),
                           v => v.Parent.Attribute("value").Value);

// Results --
// Key    Value
// ------ ----------
// 1      22.wav
// 0      22.wav
// 7      22.wav
// 13     22.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your query below is answer but it will throw error as we must have unique Key in dictionary.

```
  XDocument po = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
            var data = po.Descendants("key")
       .ToDictionary(
           el => (string)el.Element("value"),
           el => (int)el.Attribute("Index"));
```

and if u take index as key and value as value then go for below code

```
XDocument po = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
                var data = po.Descendants("key")
           .ToDictionary(
               el => (int)el.Element("Index"),
               el => (string)el.Attribute("value"));
```

but for your query u can use

```
var disc = Dictionary<string, IList<int>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

each key will have a list of values. 
This might not be the best solution though, but it will fit your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to generate `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` from that XML :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var result = doc.Root.Elements("key")
                   .GroupBy(k => (string)k.Attribute("value"))
                   .ToDictionary(o => int.Parse(o.Key), 
                                 p => p.Select(q => (string)q.Element("Index")).ToList());
```